# Why do I get SIGSEGV when dereferencing $esp?

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, stack, dereference

I'm debugging a small assembly program I wrote and I get a Segmentation Fault every time.
It's compiled as 64bit.

```
section     .text
global      _start                              ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:                                         ;tell linker entry point
  mov eax, 1
  mov eax, 2
  mov eax, 3
  mov eax, 4
  mov eax, 5
  mov eax, 6
  push 'A'
  mov edx, [esp] ; Here's where it crashes
  call putc
  add esp, 4  

  mov     eax,1                               ;system call number (sys_exit)
  int     0x80                                ;call kernel

%include "utils.inc"
```

As I understood, the head of the stack (what goes into `$edx`) should be 'A'.
How come I have no access to the head of the stack?

Comment: Are you assembling this as 64-bit code or 32-bit code? How do you know it crashes at `mov edx, [esp] ; Here's where it crashes` ?

Comment: Should also point out that if you are the _C_ library `putc` it requires a FILE * as the second parameter. I can't tell if you are using the _C_ library `putc` or if it was something defined in `utils.inc`

Comment: It's 64bit code. I know because I debugged it using gdb and that `putc` is my own prodecure written in `utils.inc` and I guess it's irrelevant because the program crashes before it.

Comment: If you are writing 64-bit code you need to be using `rsp` (64-bit stack pointer) and not `esp` (32-bit stack pointer). Depending on what system calls you are making you should be using the `syscall` instruction and not `int 0x80` for 64-bit code. If passing pointers to a system call you'll need 64-bit pointers which are only available via `syscall` instruction. `syscall` and `int 0x80` also vary in the way parameters are passed and the system call numbers are different.

Comment: The only way I could think of that `mov edx, [esp]` would fail is if you were writing 64-bit code. Changing `esp` to `rsp` should resolve that issue.

Comment: Didn't think about that... Thank you guys!